# When should I set the AllowUnsafeUpdates property?

Tags: spweb

It mentioned that we should set "AllowUnsafeUpdates" to true, when the web object is not created from the SPContext.

However should I still need to set as mentioned below?

```
SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

// Perform the list/list item/web update 
web.allowUnsafeUpdates = false;
```

Comment: The suggested post does not have the answer, this is still not clear whether to use or not on the above mentioned scenario.

Answer (score 1):

No. There is no reason to use unsafe updates in your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will need need to use AllowUnsafeUpdates = true, and afterwards, AllowUnsafeUpdates = false - this is to prevent your from cross-site scripting attacks.

**SPWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates** : Gets/Sets a Boolean value that specifies whether to allow updates to the database as a result of a GET request or without requiring a security validation. Whenever your code modifies SharePoint data in some way or Whenever we need to update SharePoint objects like SPWeb, SPList, SPListItem, etc , without requiring a security validation, we need to set SPWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true.

[Source](http://sharepoint.infoyen.com/2012/03/24/spweb-allowunsafeupdates/)

The following stack overflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/213882/1539718) provides some additional context on best practice, and use.